# Saving WordPress functions.php fails arbitrarily with message "Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved"

Tags: php, wordpress

While I was working in functions.php in WordPress it seems to fail arbitrarily. Sometimes it would save and when saving again it would suddenly fail. Also, even after clearing everything from functions.php (so with a completely empty file) it wouldn't even safe.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Take a look at the console and the network tab in your browser's devtools.

Comment: are you using theme editor or ftp?